# 'Patriotism' is to 'Country' as _______ is to 'City'

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, analogy

The title's pretty self explanatory! I can't seem to find a word which means exactly this, but I would be amazed if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Patriotism comes from the Latin word *patria*, which means *country*.  If another word were coined I would guess it would be along the lines of *urbism*.

Comment: I reverted the edits; coining new terms isn't really recommended without a good reason for it.

Comment: @MrHen Fair enough. What qualifies as a good reason?

Comment: We have a [meta discussion](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1216/requests-for-coinage) for that. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite right, but perhaps closer than other suggestions:

> 'Patriotism' is to 'Country' as [*parochialism*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parochial) is to 'City'.

To summarize the link, *parochial* means of a church parish, of a parish as a unit of local government, or confined to a parish.  The link gives synonyms of [narrow](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/narrow) and [provincial](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/provincial) for parochial.

Comment: @Peter Could you please add a brief summary of the linked information?  Thanks.

Comment: @user8809: Try that.

Comment: Parochial is similar to national. It doesn't have the loyalty/devotion factor that is in patriotism.

Comment: @Peter K: Thanks.  I believe policy is to summarize links in case they break.

Comment: @user8809: Understood. I generally don't like cutting-and-pasting, though, which is what this can lead to. Paraphrasing takes longer, or more thought. :-)

Comment: @Peter K: Certainly.  Thanks again and +1

Comment: I'm not really satisfied with this answer. This word is generally chosen when one wants to de-emphasise the city itself. For instance, someone lobbying the city council to reallocate police resources from high-crime areas into their own council district would be displaying *parochialisim*, but very little spirit for their city at large.

Comment: "parochialism" does have a negative connotation of small-minded, or having limited experience of only a single small town and no knowledge of the wider world.

Comment: @Martin Beckett: As does *patriorism*.  Or just about any *-ism* for that matter.

Comment: Parochialism is a good answer. It does mean a narrow minded focus on ones own area, whether this is a neighbourhood, town, city, village or whatever. In the same way that Patriotism usually connotes a narrow minded focus on ones country. It only seems negative, of course, when you are on the outside or the parish.....

Answer (score 23):

"Civic pride" or "Civic duty": neither is as comprehensive as patriotism, but depending on context, one might work. Edit: also "civic spirit".

Comment: So instead of "he is very patriotic" you would say "he has a lot of civic pride". Not quite as punchy, but still effective, thanks.

Comment: @danoprey In that case, "He is civic-minded" might work.

Comment: @JeffSahol I would read that as in he likes to help out his community more than he is extremely proud of the city he lives in.

Comment: Just because it starts with the same two letters doesn't really link *civic* to *city*. If it did then *civicism* would be the word.

Comment: @FumbleFingers trrue, but the [derivation](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=civic) of the word is from "townsman"...I had to double check that myself before I started firing off the "civics"...not to mention the current [meaning](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/civic), of course.

Comment: @danoprey, that is correct.

Comment: @JeffSahol: I didn't know that. When I'm not thinking in terms of *civilisation*, I mostly think of *civilians* as opposed to, say, the military.

Comment: That whole etymology is very interesting...it has both national and city connotations, because it predates nationalism itself. Check out "civitas", for example: http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/secondary/SMIGRA*/Civitas.html

Comment: Civic implies civilian, and civilian applies to any level of government. Not really the same relationship.

Comment: @Xaade, if you check the definition of the word, you'll see "Of, relating to, or belonging to a *city*, a citizen, or citizenship; municipal or civil."

Answer (score 6):

Here are a few possibilities:

***local patriotism***

***localism***; ***localist***

> Devotion to local interests and customs.

***civic pride***

***sectionalism***; ***sectionalist***

> Excessive regard for sectional  or
>   local interests; regional or local
>   spirit, prejudice, etc.

*OT: There is a great term in Italian, *campanilismo*:

> It would be unwise to play down the overwhelming spirit of campanilismo (local patriotism; the spirit of “our campanile is taller than yours”) during the 14th and 15th centuries.

The term refers to the bragging rights one could attain through one's town having a taller belltower than the neighboring towns.  It has become a general term for pride in your hometown and its local products.

Comment: +1 for *campanilismo*, even though it's not the English term. As a side note, "local patriotism" is how we describe the notion in German, so there we also lack a word.

Answer (score 3):

The word I think is closest to this is *[boosterism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boosterism)*. It perhaps has an evangelical connotation that *patriotism* does not, but I think that's inherent in the difference between a city and a country. (There are significantly less onerous barriers to city residency changes than country residency changes.)

Comment: For my money, this is the right answer, which I've up-voted. This term is reminiscent of Babbitt, of course.

Comment: It should be noted, though, that this term will be readily understood only by the speakers of American English.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase ***civic patriotism*** actually has a lot more currency than I expected if you search for it on Google. Seemed to be especially used at the end of the 19th century and beginning of the 20th century.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to grapple with this as a translator myself (as the language I am translating from simply uses "patriot" in this role). I went with "proud citizen of city_name."

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there is a region-but-not-country-specific answer other than *pride*.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately 'pride' doesn't fit my needs. Care to have a go at coining the term?

Answer (score -1):

Aside from *nationalism*, *patriotism*, *ethnocentrism* and the dubious *culturalism*, the best you will likely get is the mere description of such a thing as a form of [cultural bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_bias):

> Cultural bias is the phenomenon of interpreting and judging phenomena by standards inherent to one's own culture.

This term is probably way too broad to be of much use but everything else I found wasn't really technical in nature. Something more generic:

- prejudice
- bigotry
- bias
- fandom

The last one is pretty close:

> Fandom is a term used to refer to a subculture composed of fans characterized by a feeling of sympathy and camaraderie with others who share a common interest.

The negative side of *fandom* are [*fanboys*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fanboy#Fanboy.2Ffangirl):

> Fanboy is a term used to describe a male who is highly devoted and biased in opinion towards a single subject or hobby within a given field. Fanboy-ism is often prevalent in a field of products, brands or universe of characters where very few competitors exist.

A description of a *Seattle fanboy* would provide the appropriate meaning. The only drawback to this is that it would likely be associated with the relevant sports team if said in a bar on a Sunday.

You can use the same form but drop the *-boy* for a kinder approach:

> John is a NYC fan
>
> Joan is a fan of Jersey

With, again, the entire group of fans being the fandom:

> The Chicago fandom trods on